# laravel : convert sqk to laravel OEM

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Please how to convert this sql query to Laravel eloquent ?
 The SQl :

```
select n.element, n.type, n.note
        from notes AS n
        inner join (
            SELECT element, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount
            FROM notes
            GROUP BY element
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS oc on n.element = oc.element
```

I tired to convert it to laravel using DB select and worked but i want to add where in end and use this code in foreach loop as where argument changed but it's not working due to put argument in signe quote

Please could you help me ?

Comment: Show us the code you tried and we'll help you correct the mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eloquent to get the subquery.

And join the subquery look like this, and you can use `mergeBindings` to bind the parameters:

```php
$sub_query = Note::groupBy('element')
                ->having(DB::Raw('COUNT(*) > 1'))
                ->select('element', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS dupeCount'));

Note::join(DB::raw("({$sub_query->toSql()}) AS oc"), "oc.element", "=", "notes.element")
     ->mergeBindings($sub_query->getQuery())
     ->select("notes.element", "notes.type", "notes.note")
     ->get();
```

Comment: I got this error : 
ErrorException
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: i fixed the issue in your code was juste delete db::table from 1 param on join